# What's the key information in a cashback UI

Tags: usability, gui-design

[image]

I am building an interface where users view details about cashback they receive for x. The cashback is supposed to be re-used within the application for ordering x again.

As I understand it, the key information is the amount of cashback users have in their account, along with any upcoming amounts that will be paid within the next fortnight.

Further information is available in a tabular form under this primary information in bold.

I believe the total amount of cash back since inception is not a key piece of information for the users. However, that can be displayed in the options link. The options link will also house the business-unfriendly option to withdraw the cash to user's bank account.

Am I focusing on the right areas?

Comment: Sidenote: Is "Fortnight" commonly used in Australia? In the eastern US (imo?) it sounds very strange and would make me uncomfortable with it being used in a financial app. I would suggest just saying "two weeks". This is essentially how I perceive the word https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/fortnight

Comment: The term "Cashback" might lead the users to believe they can actually get...cash back.  If it can only be spent within the store you need some other term like "credits", I think.

Comment: @dan1111 this is actually cash back. The anti-pattern is that it would be available as credit first, and if the user really wants to, she can get real cash back.

Comment: @DasBeasto thanks so much for pointing this out. I am not a native English speaker so this won't have stood out for me.

Comment: @DasBeasto Yes, 'fortnight' is very common in Australia. It's good to know though that it's not necessarily common in other parts of the world.

Comment: Displaying the "amount of cash since inception" might be a good retention tool - It tells the user that the service has a greater value to them in the long term: "hey user, look how much cash you been able to use with us!" - Having said that, I agree that it's probably not a 'key' piece of information. Have you spoken to target users to find out what they want to see?

Answer (score 1):

Most sites will use cashback just like any other regular payment, Amazon for example lets you opt in to always spend your points, it will be subtracted from the total on checkout, your table does not show any values for subtotal, total, tax etc.

1. add a total to the bottom of your items list
2. don't make the table be more lines then neccessary
3. subtract cashback from this total.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to enrich the data in following ways:

1. Remove order number with actual text like " coffee at starbuks"
2. Remove the serial no column
3. Render the latest data first in the table
4. Fix the position of cash back box and let the table be scrollable

Segregation of cash back details on the basis of forthnight or month. Although, I'm not sure about the functional information about the application.